# How can I change div position on scroll (depending on the direction of scroll)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I would like to reproduce the scrolling effect used on weebly's home page: http://www.weebly.com/

I believe they are detecting the scroll direction and changing div positions depending on the direction. (using a transition for the animation)

Any ideas on how I could achieve the same effect possibly without Jquery? 
If there's another way to do it I would be happy to see it too.

Comment: You might take a look at this: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Comment: try `style="position: absolute; top: 0%;"` for 1st div, then `style="position: absolute; top:100%` for next div, then `style="position: absolute; top: 200%` for next and soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like [fullPage](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) (requires jQuery) or [a pure js alternative](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/purejs_onepage_scroll_demo.html)

Comment: FullPage.js is great, very easy to use.

Comment: FullPage.js worked great! Thanks!